# How to separate desktop and mobile page and lazy load each page in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-routing

my goal is to separate `desktop` and `mobile` page. The reason is that the `desktop` page UX flow is "scroll to section". Meanwhile, the `mobile` page UX flow is "navigate to the next section".

The problem:

1. The `desktop` user will load `mobile` page. Same goes for the `mobile` user.

This is the visual diagram of the current solution:

1. there is a `main` page and `get-device-type` service.
2. the `main` page will render the `desktop` page or the `mobile` page.
   [image]

What I've tried:

1. use `canLoad` for `desktop` page.

My expectation:

1. When the `desktop` user visit path `checkout/1`, it will load the `desktop` page.
2. When the `mobile` user visit path `checkout/1`, it will not load the `desktop` page but instead load the `mobile` page.

My actual result:

1. When the `desktop` user visit path `checkout/1`, it will load the `desktop` page.
2. When the `mobile` user visit path `checkout/1`, it will not load any page.

checkout-page-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { IsDesktopGuard } from '../../../domain/usecases/is-desktop/is-desktop.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import("../checkout-scroll-page/checkout-scroll-page.module").then(m => m.CheckoutScrollPageModule),
    canLoad: [IsDesktopGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import("../checkout-navigate-page/checkout-navigate-page.module").then(m => m.CheckoutNavigatePageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CheckoutPageRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally do `loadChildren` based on the device?

```
const isMobile = {
  Android: function () {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
  },
  BlackBerry: function () {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
  },
  iOS: function () {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
  },
  Opera: function () {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
  },
  Windows: function () {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/WPDesktop/i);
  },
  any: function () {
    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
  }
};

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'desktop',
    loadChildren: () => {
      if (!isMobile.any()) {
        return import("../checkout-scroll-page/checkout-scroll-page.module").then(m => m.CheckoutScrollPageModule);
      } else {
        return import("../checkout-navigate-page/checkout-navigate-page.module").then(m => m.CheckoutNavigatePageModule);
      } 
     },
  },
];
```

Comment: this does not work in our case because sometimes iPhone user will want to open the url in desktop, and it usually do it by "share the link" and open it in a "MacBook".

Comment: @JasonRichDarmawan insert the guard on mobile also to do the redirect

Comment: No, I believe mobile and desktop path is bad for the user experience. Since it uses redirect. For example, when user press the back button. The current solution is to use canMatch guard (available since Angular 14)

Comment: Note: "Using `navigator` is not Angular Universal friendly". Thank you for the answer. I will accept this answer. Anyway, I found another solution but only exist in Angular 14. You can use `canMatch` guard and create 2 route with identical path value.